# Mongoose: Create a User schema and Todo schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Good afternoon guys. I've been working on building a little contact list app and I wanted to use mongoose for storing data and session items. I've never used mongoose before so I picked up a quick PDF to follow along with. Most of if makes sense and I was able to piece some stuff together and get authentication running to add new users using a `UserSchema`. Works great. What I'm a little lost on now is how can I use mongoose to create a second schema called `ContactSchema`. I thought I would create 2 different files for each schema (user.js and contact.js), but when I try that, I still don't see a contact collection when I run `show collections` in my mongo terminal and I also don't throw any errors. It's also the same when I check for it in robomongo.

My server file calls the all my models like this:

```
require('./server/models').connect(config.dbUri);
// config.dbUri -> "dbUri": "mongodb://localhost/react_app"
```

My user.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// define the User model schema
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: { unique: true }
  },
  password: String,
  name: String
});

...bcrypt code here

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

My contact.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define the Contact model schema
const ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content    : String,
  updated_at : Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', ContactSchema);
```

My index.js file to require both user.js and contact.js schemas:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports.connect = (uri) => {
  mongoose.connect(uri);

  // plug in the promise library
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

  mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(`Mongoose connection error: ${err}`);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  require('./user');
  require('./contact');
};
```

The index.js, user.js and contact.js files are all inside of my models folder. I can get this to run with no errors in console, but I'm still not seeing the contact collection on the mongo side. Am I on the right track here? As always any help or related posts are greatly appreciated. To get a better idea, here is the github link to the full project: https://github.com/DanDeller/Base. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you added any data to the contacts collection yet ?

Mongoose is an 'ORM' of sorts that provides abstract schemas that map to MongoDB collections.  However, these schemas exist only in the context of the application that is using mongoose.  MongoDB has no concept of schemas.  It is a fairly dum document store. It's not like SQL, where defining something in your ORM typically creates a physical table in the DB.  The schemas mongoose provides are purely abstract and only enforced at the application level.

Until you tell your application to create a record based on your contact schema and instruct mongoose to persist it to the store, mongo will have no idea of a contact.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @fluoresce. That makes sense. I'll try to add in a few items and see what I can come up with.